# how to use TM symbol in titanium UI component

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

I want to use TM (trademark symbol) while creating label.

```
Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: '© ' + (new Date().getFullYear()) + ' companyname 0xE2 0x84 0xA2',
        font: {
            fontSize: 13,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana'
        },
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        left: 3,
        bottom: 5,
        visible: false
    });
```

Previously used copyright symbol as copy-paste. but this will be last option.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it like this:

```js
var l = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: '© ' + (new Date().getFullYear()) + ' companyname \u2122',
    font: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    },
    color: '#000'
});
```

it will display **© 2020 companyname ™**

Comment: Thanks. i just got this link http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest//?mobile=/api/Titanium.UI.Label-event-link trying to search unicode till you answer.